# Calling Function which is present in another Extjs page from another Extjs page

Tags: extjs

How  to call a function which is present in one ExtJS page from another ExtJS page.

Like Function Present in one ExtJS page

```
function Orders(orders) 
{
 some operations
}
```

I have to call above  function from another extjs page

> like ---
>   Orders(orderd)-->

SO how to call this function.

Comment: and that's why you should use MVC :)

Answer (score 0):

1.you can include that page in existing html / asp/ jsp
 1. Put the page you want to call in "onReady" of that page 
 2. call here using ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Depends in what scope you defined your function.

If you just did (adding it to the window object)

```
function Orders(id){
}
```

You can call `Orders(7)` in an other file, if the function is created before you call it.

Or you can do what `@Neil McGuigan` commented: use MVC!